# Multidimensional array in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

```
int [][] a = {{1,2,},{3,4}};
int [][] a = {{1,2},{3,4}};
```

i have two Multidimensional arrays in java. I want to know what's the exact difference in both of them.just see there is a comma after 2 in first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JLS 10.6. Array Initializers: A trailing comma may appear after the last expression in an array initializer and is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. The extra comma might be useful if you are formatting your elements one per line, so that every element appears the same.